# What's the proper way to trigger the API reload from reducer/action?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I've a quite complex application that communicates with the server via websocket (for object updates) and http (for getting initial object).

But i'm facing the follow situation:

1. Get from the service all the initial objects
2. Web-socket ask to update an object that's not included on the list
3. Do another call to the service to reload the objects

So basically I've this state:

```
export const initialState: IMatchStore = {
  loading: false,
  needReload: true,
  matches: [],
};
```

And a few selectors, for example:

```
export const getAll = createSelector(
  matchSelector,
  ({ matches }: IMatchStore) => unflatMatches(matches),
);

export const isLoading = createSelector(
  matchSelector,
  ({ loading }: IMatchStore) => loading,
);

export const reload = createSelector(
  matchSelector,
  ({ needReload, loading }: IMatchStore) => !loading && needReload,
);
```

So basically when the `needReload === true` it means that I need to reload the base (this is detected on the reducer if the `match` doesn't exist on the list).

**My question is**: What's the proper way for handling this situation? Currently i'm doing on the service, like:

```
this.store.select(reload).pipe(filter(Boolean)).subscribe(() => this.load());
```

But I feel that it could be improved and wrapper inside some `effect`

---

**Update:**

I've managed to create a effect watching the `ActionTypes.Update`, but it still not looking right to me :p

```
@Effect()
login$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(ActionTypes.Update),
    withLatestFrom(this.store.select(reload)),
    filter(([, needRealod]) => needRealod),
    switchMapTo(
      forkJoin( /** HTTP stuff */ ).pipe(
        map(([a, b]) => new Init(a, b)),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Comment: Just to double check, you are using `switchMapTo` you want to call "HTTP stuff" only once and then return same action for all further `ActionTypes.Update`

Answer (score 1):

The updated answer you posted is in my eyes the way to go.

- This keeps your application clean
- The effect can easily be tested

See [Start using ngrx/effects for this](https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/start-using-ngrx-effects-for-this) for another example.